# Setting application version in CMake to call from QCoreApplication::applicationVersion

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm working on a C++ Qt application using CMake as the build tool on Windows. A class constructor within the application uses the QCoreApplication library to get the application name and application version through applicationName and applicationVersion respectively:

```
ClassName::ClassName(QObject* parent) :
  Property1(parent),
  classState(Stopped),
  autoStart(false),
  appName(qApp->applicationName()), // is set to "myAppName" when debugging
  appVersion(qApp->applicationVersion()), // is blank when debugging
  outputFileName(DEFAULT_OUT_NAME),
  metaInfo(nullptr)
 {
 
 }
```

I know that the application **name** is set in the top-level CMake file as such:

```
add_executable(myAppName
    ${SOURCES}
    ##${HEADERS}  <--not needed
)
```

However, I'm not sure where Qt gets the application **version** from.

I've used:

```
set_target_properties(myAppName PROPERTIES 
                      VERSION 11.12
                      SOVERSION 1.5)
```

after add_executable, but neither the VERSION nor the SOVERSION shows up when debugging the class constructor. Clearing the CMake configuration does nothing, as does cleaning/rebuilding the solution as a whole.

I understand there is the function QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion, but I'd rather see if there is anything in CMake first. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: cmake properties only work for cmake configuration, it is not used in the source code. What you want is to define a variable in cmake and use it in your source code and that can be done with definition

Comment: Great, this actually solves another issue not mentioned here. Thanks